# Simplify ifPresentOrElse chain

Tags: java, option-type, chain

Given the code:

```
  Optional<String> myOptional = getMyOptional();
  myOptional.ifPresentOrElse(
      s -> Optional.ofNullable(someMap.get(s))
      .ifPresentOrElse(g -> {
            doSomeStuff(); 
          },
          () -> doErrHandling()),
      () -> doErrHandling());
```

Now I am thinking about how to simplify the chain and remove the duplicate code line (`() -> doErrHandling()`).

Comment: Looks simple unless you want to use `g` in your actual code as `if (myOptional.isPresent() && someMap.containsKey(myOptional.get())) {
            doSomeStuff();
        } else {
            doErrHandling();
        }`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `map`:

```
Optional<String> myOptional = getMyOptional() ;
myOptional.map(s -> someMap.get(s))
          .ifPresentOrElse(g -> doSomeStuff(), () -> doErrHandling());
```

`map` will return an `Optional.empty()` if the original `Optional` is empty, and will wrap the result of `someMap.get(s)` with an `Optional` otherwise.

Comment: This is the correct answer. May just use `someMap::get` if desired.